# Unable to extend Node_Literal Jena class

Tags: java, rdf, semantics, jena, semantic-web

I am trying to write implementation of jena graph API and while implementing it. I am  facing problem in extending Node_Literal class which  is a jena class for literal values. While extending it, it is giving this error "The constructor Node_Literal(Object) is not visible"

The code of parent class (Node_Literal) is following:

```
public class Node_Literal extends Node_Concrete{

Node_Literal( Object label )
    { super( label ); }

@Override
public LiteralLabel getLiteral()
    { return (LiteralLabel) label; }

@Override
public final Object getLiteralValue()
    { return getLiteral().getValue(); }

@Override
public final String getLiteralLexicalForm()
    { return getLiteral().getLexicalForm(); }

@Override
public final String getLiteralLanguage()
    { return getLiteral().language(); }

@Override
public final String getLiteralDatatypeURI()
    { return getLiteral().getDatatypeURI(); }

@Override
public final RDFDatatype getLiteralDatatype()
    { return getLiteral().getDatatype(); }

@Override
public final boolean getLiteralIsXML()
    { return getLiteral().isXML(); }

@Override
public String toString( PrefixMapping pm, boolean quoting )
    { return ((LiteralLabel) label).toString( quoting ); }

@Override
public boolean isLiteral() 
    { return true; }    

/**
    Literal nodes defer their indexing value to the component literal.
    @see com.hp.hpl.jena.graph.Node#getIndexingValue()
*/
@Override
public Object getIndexingValue()
    { return getLiteral().getIndexingValue(); }

@Override
public Object visitWith( NodeVisitor v )
    { return v.visitLiteral( this, getLiteral() ); }

@Override
public boolean equals( Object other )
    {
    if ( this == other ) return true ;
    return other instanceof Node_Literal && label.equals( ((Node_Literal) other).label );
    }

@Override
public boolean sameValueAs(Object o) {
    return o instanceof Node_Literal 
          && ((LiteralLabel)label).sameValueAs( ((Node_Literal) o).getLiteral() );
}

@Override
public boolean matches( Node x )
    { return sameValueAs( x ); }

}
```

Class that is extending node literal is given below:

```
public class JenaNeoLiteral extends Node_Literal{

    protected JenaNeoLiteral(Object label) {

        super(label);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Which version of Jena is this because the current code says:

```
/* package */ Node_Literal( Object label )
```

i.e. noting the package scope.

The project has been discussing (careful!) changes to Node recently - you may wish to join that conversation on the dev@ mailing list at jena.apache.org.

Why do you extend  to extend Node_Literal? You be better off extending Node itself.

Because the semantics of all Nodes is by-value, then just because you create one and put it in a graph, you may get back a different instance when you retrieve it.  Literals are particularly sensitive to this because of carrying the value around.

The SPARQL engine, uses its own NodeValue in SPARQL expression evaluation so as to have different semantics (specific XSD evaluation) without changing the semantics when stored in hash maps etc.

Comment: Here's a link to the [constructor for `Node_Literal`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.jena/jena-core/2.11.0/com/hp/hpl/jena/graph/Node_Literal.java#Node_Literal.%3Cinit%3E%28java.lang.Object%29) as a reference (for others).